# High-performance .NET sweep/oscilloscope graph component needed

Tags: .net, winforms, charts, graph, oscilloscope

I'm searching for a .NET graph component. It should be able to plot data in sweep (oscilloscope) mode and if possible also as a scrolling waveform. On the x-axis I want timestamps (e.g. 18:25:00) and it should be possible to plot two vectors (DateTime[] and double[]). That is, data points are not equally spaced, but come with their own timestamps. Performance is of the essence; it should be able to scroll/display data on a reasonably slow machine. In addition I'd like multiple (up to 12) y-axes on the same graph, i.e. stacked waveforms. Data will be arriving pretty quickly, e.g. 10 channels each sampled at 1000 Hz with a block of data every 200 ms. Ideas anyone?

Comment: For clarification what is reasonably slow and with which version of Windows? The opinion of slow can vary greatly.

Comment: True! For development I'm using a laptop equipped with an AMD Turion 64 X2 @ 2 GHz. Right now, the graph component from NI I've been using barely keeps up at 50++ % CPU usage.

Comment: I ended up using the NI Measurement Studio components anyway. They lack in performance, but on a reasonably fast machine and moderate screen resolution they perform acceptably. In addition, no other components I've evaluated can measure up to the features offered by Measurement Studio. That is: cursors, annotations, plot/line options.

Comment: Full disclosure, I am the owner of gigasoft.com but your problem describes very close to what Gigasoft ProEssentials provides.  See the demo or eval, example 123 that plots real-time waveform data with a time scale exactly as you describe.  Example 123 does use an added feature for event based x axis formatting. ProEssentials also handles date-time double precision with dynamic time x axes, non equally spaced data, direct3d/dx rendering is very fast, and optionally (if a target system does not have discreet graphics) our Direct2D and GDI is quite fast as it has lossless data reduction logic.

Answer (score 3):

Try [LightningChart](http://www.arction.com/) as they seem to do the fastest charts in the market for oscilloscope style applications.

Answer (score 0):

LightningChart IS very powerful, but beware that their legend control absolutely sucks and is, IMHO, unusable.

Answer (score -2):

I have some experience with TeeChart ( http://www.steema.com/teechart/net ), but I don't think it's appropriate for what you want to do. It's probably not going to be fast enough.

If it's possible to use WPF, you may want to take a look at Visiblox ( http://www.visiblox.com/ ).